# How to prevent self-charging in parallel UPS?

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi, ups

I'm trying to design an UPS for Raspberry Pi that **only connects to +5V and GND pin.**

[image]

PMIC1 is a battery charger connected to a 5V boost. [source](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465)

U1 is a voltage supervisor that serves as UVLO (PMIC1 has no UVLO for battery).

When power to the Pi is disconnected, the boost output will provide power to the Pi. However it will also charge the battery since it's also connected to the Vbus (battery charger input).

I realized this probably cannot be solved with a few diodes or FETs. The only thing I can think of is something that disconnect Vbus when there is current going out of 5V0 pin.

Comment: Generally UPS circuits use a small microcontroller to manage the flow of power as it's not possible to implement all the desired functionality with just diodes. It needs memory and several states to be effective. You may still struggle to implement it only from a single pin, unless you somehow use 5.1 V as the signal for mains power, and 4.9 V as the battery supplied voltage. A series UPS, where you supply 7 V and it then supplies 5 V to the Pi, can be done with only diodes.

Comment: @tomnexus could you please provide an example or explain the logic ?

Comment: Sure - the 7 V PSU feeds the Pi via a regulator and a (schottkey) diode. Also it feeds the battery charger. The battery has a boost converter, which feeds the Pi via another Schottkey diode. Set the mains regulator slightly higher than the boost convertor so it takes over powering the Pi when the mains is on. You can see if you need much more than that, a microcontroller is probably the simplest way to make it do what you need.

Comment: @tomnexus My goal is to make the UPS power and feed off RPi from the same pin. So I cannot use higher voltage or regulator. How about a current sensor on boost output(5V0), a logic-level FET switch on Vbus, and a micocontroller shuts the Vbus when there is current going out of the boost?

Answer (score 0):

That module takes care of most of that for you.  Connect the battery to the BAT terminal and the RPi to the VS terminal through a suitable buck-boost converter.  Edit: the onboard boost converter on the board should work too.

Comment: What about Vbus ? leave it float? that way the battery will never charge.

Comment: Connect it to your power source.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but you would connect the charge-through module only to the +5V and GND pins on the RPi.  I.e. instead of connecting it in parallel with the 5V source powering the RPi, you would put it inline.  If you want it in parallel, you'd need a different module.

Comment: Sry I didn't explain clearly enough. The goal is to make a parallel UPS, that PMIC1 only connects to 5V and GND. I don't want to make serial UPS because the board can only source 2A. Also I hate to add another USB socket.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do.  You might be able to play around within the 4.75-5.25V input voltage range of the Pi; e.g. have the battery circuit output at 4.8V and charge if the input voltage rises above that.  Changing some component values on your module might make it possible but I'm not bullish on that.  It should be possible with a common off-the-shelf charge controller and some voltage sensing circuitry since you don't need charge-through capability.